# Unit test with Moq

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, moq

I am using Moq for unit testing, and I am trying to write my first unit test. My layers are "Controller=>Service=>Repository".

(I am using unity and repository pattern.)

Whenever I run my unit test, the actual value is always `0` like `_service.GetEquipStates().Count() = 0`. I do not know where I am doing wrong. Please suggest.

My unit test code is the following one:

```
private ITestService _service;
private Mock<ITestRepository> RepositoryMoc; 

[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize() { 
    RepositoryMoc= new Mock<ITestRepository>(); 
    _service = new TestService(RepositoryMoc.Object) 
}
[TestMethod]
public void GetEquipmentState() {   
    var stateList = new[] { new State { ID = 1, Desc= "test" } };         
    RepositoryMoc.Setup(es => es.GetStates(true)).Returns(stateList );     
    Assert.AreEqual(1, _service.GetStates().Count());           
}
```

Comment: Please also post the code for `TestService.GetStates()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is done for the methode GetState with prameter true.

```
RepositoryMoc.Setup(es => es.GetStates(true)).Returns(stateList);
```

But your call in the Assert-Statement is for a method GetState without a parameter. Is the method GetState declared with a default parameter or do you have to functions (one with a bool parameter and one without)?

Just make your call in the assert-statement like this and it should work.

```
Assert.AreEqual(1, _service.GetStates(true).Count());
```

Answer (score 1):

I have replicated your code in one of my solutions, and the test passes fine.

```
    private Mock<IAccessor> RepositoryMoc;
    private Controller _service;

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        // Arrange
        _service = new Controller();
        RepositoryMoc = new Mock<IAccessor>();

        _service.Accessor = RepositoryMoc.Object;

        var stateList = new[] { new State { ID = 1, Desc = "test" } };
        RepositoryMoc.Setup(es => es.GetStates(true)).Returns(stateList);

        // Act & Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, _service.GetStates().Count());           
    }
```

Is the code exactly as is in your solution ?